# Unable to download a file through requests after getting url from selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

While working with selenium webdriver, I want to set download location to a particular location and work with the headless browser. But I am unable to do both at once. Upon going headless, download location changes back. 
Here is the piece of my code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",{
    "download.default_directory":os.getcwd()+"\mydir",
    "download.prompt_for_download":False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True
})
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: So, without `--headless`, it saves downloads to `mydir`, yes? Where does it save downloads to without `--headless`?

Comment: Actually download is not happening at all in headless mode. I was searching for the downloaded file but was unable to get it. But, it was not in the desired location. Thanks, fir the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [chromedriver does not currently support headless downloads](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1973).